# PhpDoc сервер, с автоматическим обновлением. Существует ли

Tags: php, phpdoc

Сейчас использую по крону git pull и построение документации с phpDocumentor.phar

Существует ли в природе готовое серверное решение, автоматизирующее задачи по обновлению документации PHP кода? К примеру отслеживая git-репозитории.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно. Это из серии CI. Необходимо синхронизировать ваш репозиторий с Jenkins или Travis (или другой CI тулзой) . В выбранной CI вы сможете выполнять **любые** скрипты по вашему усмотрению: генерацию документации, юнит-тесты, автоматические сборки и тд. 
Если вы используете в качестве гит сервера что-то популярное типа github или bitbucket, то сможете это сделать без особых [знаний](https://github.com/integrations/travis-ci)

в этой области.